# What life would thrive on land which is frequently -- but not always -- doused with seawater?

Tags: ecology, sea-creatures, sea

Take a large piece of normally-dry land and flood it twice a day with seawater. We expect to see seaweed, crabs, and the like set up an ecosystem.

The flooding is tens of metres deep, and turbulent, so all sorts of life forms might get churned up and deposited in pools.

In my scenario this starts and stops cyclically. You get a couple of dry weeks followed by a couple of wet weeks.

I expect a lot of things to die and rot during the dry weeks. But what else can we say about this semi-saltwater ecosystem? What will thrive?

(There is not enough time for evolution to bring about any adaptation.)

Comment: That's too big a flood to get interrupted by such a small time as several weeks. It could only be caused by tidal effects of a nearby moon/planet, and stopping tidal waves bor several periods is deemed impossible (since they are then to return). I'm not sure what, if any, can cause tidal effects to at least partly cease and not break the planetary system.

Comment: just look at coastal salt marsh, mud flat, estuary and other coastline flora, to me it seems you're describing something that real world exists, you don't need us for that .. mangrove trees flourish in many coastal saltwater regions for a start.

Answer (score 3):

The [Bay of Fundy](https://www.bayoffundy.com/about/highest-tides/) has tides of up to 16 meters. The Severn estuary in the UK has tides over 12 meters. The tidal region in both cases looks fairly barren. I would imagine if nothing lived there at all, then something would move in, but I expect it would burrow under the sands to avoid drying out, or to avoid the predators from land, sea, and air.

In your case, the flooding takes several weeks rather than twice a day so there will be less currents, and you may have rock pools that last a while.

Comment: You probably misread - OP states the flooding happens twice per day for several weeks, then stalls for several more weeks, then repeats. However your answer looks right - the flooded part would be barren due to too much energies brought in to break all life that managed to be there, by sheer change of environment.

Comment: Thanks. It is not clear. Does the tide go in and out twice a day superimposed on a larger two-week cycle between wet and dry. Ir is it like spring and neap tides? It doesn't make a lot of difference.

Comment: Tide goes in and out twice a day for a couple of weeks, then is absent for a couple of weeks. I imagine the drying and decomposition will change things.

Comment: There's plenty of stuff like razor clams in the mud of those estuaries but not a lot of flora, but if the climate was warmer I'm sure mangrove would thrive there.